# Unable to bind the searched text in the repeater in c#

Tags: c#

I am trying to search the text(keywords) among the list which are bind to the repeater controller.I have a pagination implemented using the Data List. If I search the text, I will get the data source count as one, but if I check the result view "Enumeration yielded no results" error will come and the repeater will have no value

Here is my code

```
 string authorname = AuthorNames();
                    string ProdTitle = ProductTitle();
                    string refno = ProductRefno();
                    List<Product> ProductList = GetProductDetails(categoryName, refno, ProdTitle, authorname);
                    pageDataSource.DataSource = ProductList;
                    pageDataSource.AllowPaging = true;
                    pageDataSource.PageSize = Convert.ToInt16(ddlPageSize.SelectedValue);
                    pageDataSource.CurrentPageIndex = CurrentPage;
                    lnkbtnNext.Enabled = !pageDataSource.IsLastPage;
                    lnkbtnPrevious.Enabled = !pageDataSource.IsFirstPage;
                    ViewState["totpage"] = pageDataSource.PageCount;
                    repproductlist.DataSource = pageDataSource;
                    repproductlist.DataBind();
                    DoPaging();
                   // Int32 value = Convert.ToInt32(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PaginationDisplayAt"]);
                    if (ProductList.Count > PaginationDisplayAt)
                    {
                        this.paginationDiv.Visible = true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.paginationDiv.Visible = false;
                    }
```

any help will be usefull

Comment: where is your attempt to search the list?

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to create a new list from the search result before you bind it.

```
repproductlist.DataSource = pageDataSource.FindAll(x => x.Text.Contains(searchString)).ToList();
```

Comment: I am sending the searched text to the Database and getting the filtered result from the database itself

Comment: yea thats better i guess